# How to limit generic return type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to make a function that will try running provided function, and will throw unless it returns a truthy value, like this:

```
function test<T>(runnable: () => T): T {
    const value = runnable();
    if (! value) throw new Error(`Only truthy`);
    return value;
}

const a = test(() => {
    return (Math.random() < 0.5) ? undefined : "ok";
});

console.log(a);
```

How do I change the definition of `test` so that TS knows that `a` is always a string, not `string|undefined`?

Comment: Have it return `NonNullable<T>` instead of just `T`. This will produce an error on the return line however, but I would just use a type cast or an `@ts-ignore` comment for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the falsy types part of inner function return type, but *not* part of the outer function type, then this is possible:

First, make a `Falsy` type alias:

```
type Falsy = false | null | undefined | 0 | ''
```

And now make a union with `T` for the inner function return type:

```
function test<T>(runnable: () => T | Falsy): T {
    const value = runnable();
    if (!value) throw new Error(`Only truthy`);
    return value;
}
```

This means that `T` is inferred to *not* include the `Falsy` types. And the inner `runnable` function is allowed to return `T` or any `Falsy` type. Then you check for the `Falsy` type and proceed to the return only if the value is not a `Falsy`, which must be a `T`.

Now this function has a return type of `"ok"` since the error traps all other results.

```
const a = test(() => {
    return (Math.random() < 0.5) ? undefined : "ok";
});

a // type: "ok"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgGwM4igXigM0U6AfKAOwFcEEoDjCATCTAS0ImoqgAZWByTgWACh+mKgGNg9APaEowCEmAAeACoA+ABQAnKoTgAjBBABcUVQEp0yqItbxkIE0asBvflFdRhkuVABuiYtAxNQm09CFMAbhc3ekxjAEJfBH8zYAALdXEAdyIIbIBRdQz1VQADAHlCBFRgTTSQEpNIvjcodQhgYnUpRP8mgF9+fg9CLzh0aVlgVVNzKGdmtzaOruMAWTg0gDp1OBpxAFsZ+XZNgFYzAH4oKloGJhYjACJxAGtH-sbBvmGkcX1NhDiADmqjgnz4AHoIS0YVAAHoXIA)